# Парсинг изменяющегося div jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть сайт, на котором есть блок `div`, в нем есть изменяющиеся `div`
когда захожу в инспектор в браузере их видно нормально, но когда начинаю их парсить выдает вот это

```
        <transition-group name="id" tag="div" class="users_id">
            <div class="id" v-for="user_id" v-bind:class="id.class"
                 :key="JSON.stringify(id)"></div>
        </transition-group>
```

Возможно ли отсюда парсить дивы которые мне нужны?

Comment: Если браузер и jsoup получают разные страницы, возможно, страница после загрузки модифицируется с помощью javascript. В этом случае jsoup бессилен, но можно использовать Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы парсите SPA приложение, jsoup получает исходный код, html, который был до обработки js приложением. К сожалению, jsoup не сможет вытащить нужные данные. Вы можете посмотреть в сторону selenium

Comment: так и сделал. Спасибо